# Give an example of a function such that  '(0) exists but lim→0 () does not exist.

Tags: derivatives

Give an example of a function such that   $f’(0)$ exists but $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}f(x)$$ does not exist.

Hello, I am struggling to find an example of this? Much help, thanks!

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: If $f'(0)$ exists, then $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=0,$ and hence $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0}f(x)$ exists. Therefore, there is no such example.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the common rigorous definition of the derivative, differentiability implies continuity, and for a function continuous in 0, we have that $\lim_{x\to0}f(x) = f(0)$, in particular the limit exists.

Sometimes at a discontinuity there can be a left and a right limit of the derivative, and when they are equal their common vale is taken as the derivative. An example would be a function that is 0 up to and including 0, and 1 for $x>0$.

Comment: There is only one accepted definition of derivative. That definition is equivalent to the statement that the left and right limits defining the derivative exist and are equal **and** that the the function is continuous. Your example (the characteristic function of the interval $(0, \infty)$) does not have a derivative at $0$.

Comment: @RobArthan I don't think that is contradicting what I said

Comment: You said that sometimes the common value of the left and right derivative is taken to be the derivative at a discontinuity. That does not agree with the accepted definition of the derivative.

Comment: @RobArthan Yes, which I also say (assuming the common rigorous definition this is not possible, in the first paragraph). Which is why I suspect that OP's text does not follow the accepted definition, but maybe something like the other (which is actually stated our implied in some physics or engineering texts)

Comment: Feel free to edit if you think this was unclear